# how to repeat the first row from tablix in every page of the report(pdf,excel word)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, pdf, rdlc, ssrs-tablix

I have a large report(basically is a large tablix) with multiple pages.
I don't want to use page header because I can't insert tablix there.

i tried this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627566%28SQL.105%29.aspx
but when I open the pdf the header is not on every page